# Could not resolve artifact org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:sources

Tags: java, maven, nexus, openapi-generator

I am trying to implement openapi plugin generator , but when i run `mvn clean install` I get the following error.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:sources:${openapi-generator-version}
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$4(MavenImpl.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:773)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>company</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>company</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/test.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/</output>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <strictSpec>true</strictSpec>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <configOptions>
                                <controllerThrowsExceptions>java.io.IOException,com.example.NotFoundException</controllerThrowsExceptions>
                                <library>spring-mvc</library>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <useClassLevelBeanValidation>false</useClassLevelBeanValidation>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <useOptional>false</useOptional>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <apiPackage>${codegen.api.package.name}</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>${codegen.model.page.name}</modelPackage>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have been looking at the documentation and it seems that the repository is on nexus ?

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator

Comment: It looks like you may have to set the openapi-generator-version property as the snippet pulling in the sources use it.

Comment: The output `org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:sources:${openapi-generator-version}` shows that something in your configuration is wrong? Please show your full pom file ...

Comment: done, i've add my pom.xml to my post